# how do I get the full list of data when queried JIRA through command line

Tags: python, jira-rest-api

When I query JIRA from the command line using their REST api with this query:

`project = PROJECTNAME AND "Build Info" ~ BUILDNAME`

It only shows a maximum of 50 results even though there are a total of 892. When queried from the JIRA UI, it shows the full list, so it looks like there is a limit on the returned results.  How do I get the full list of data? Any pointers are very much appeciated.

OUTPUT:

```
........

u'maxResults': 50,
u'startAt': 0,
u'total': 892}
```

CODE:

```
.......
serverURL = 'https://jira.company.com/jira'
query = 'project = PROJECTNAME AND "Build Info" ~ BUILDNAME
jql = '/rest/api/2/search?jql=%s' % urllib.quote(query)
response = requests.get(serverURL + jql,verify=False,auth=(user, password))
```

Comment: I came across https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/changing-maxresults-parameter-for-jira-rest-api-779160706.html which states JIRA property `jira.search.view.default.max` needs to be changed,does anyone how to change this through command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50 is a default value for "maxResults" parameter. Here's API documentation https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#api/2/search-search

You need to use the startAt param and loop to get all your results, or use the maxResults param to get them all at once.

This questionhas  been asked many times ;)

Comment: have you seen any python related documentation on this?